# How can I access the H2-console while using Spring Security (Spring Boot 3.0.2)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

So I am trying to learn Spring because I'll need it for a project later on this year. Project is using Spring Boot 3.0.2 and Java 17. I am also using the Spring Security dependency, which means that I'll need to authorize some URL's without using tokens.

I found a way to do that for all URL's except the H2-console. For some reason, no matter how I write the code, I can't access the H2-console because I'll get 403(Unauthorized) when going to localhost:8080/h2-console.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

This is the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>newproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>newproject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the application.properties file:

```
#For h2 database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

## H2 specific settings
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

This is the WebSecurityConfig class:

```
package com.example.newproject.configs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
            "/register",
            "/api/v1/getUsers",
            "/h2-console/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // FIXME: Cant access h2 console
//        http
//                .cors()
//                .and()
//                .csrf()
//                .disable()
//                .authorizeHttpRequests()
//                .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS)
//                .permitAll();
//
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS).permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA386.png)

As you can see, I tried to do this in 2 ways. Both work for "/register" and "/api/v1/getUsers", but do not work for "/h2-console/**". I might be doing something wrong, but the commented code is from a youtube guide and the uncommented code is from another question on StackOverflow, so I am all out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: Problem was solved by the marked answers. This is the code that works for me:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final AntPathRequestMatcher[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/getUsers"),
            // new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"),
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS)
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, when `requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS)` is used, it will fall into the `MvcRequestMatcher` ([Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/50bbe88a2e7971155f53a1dabdb37b17c593a06e/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java#L181-L190)). The `MvcRequestMatcher` will only match against the Web MVC DispatcherServlet internal mappings. The H2 Console is not part of the DispatcherServlet by default, but the custom controllers in the application are, hence the difference.

One option to fix it is by using an `AntPathRequestMatcher` for H2 Console like so:

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    // some of the original code was omitted for brevity

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
            "/register",
            "/api/v1/getUsers"
    };

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"))
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

A possible alternative is to use an array of `AntPathRequestMatcher` instead of an array of `String` for the whitelist, and keep the security filter as-is:

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    // some of the original code was omitted for brevity

    private static final AntPathRequestMatcher[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/getUsers"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")
    };

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS)
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Another option is to add a customizer to ignore H2 Console, which should be fine since H2 Console has its own authentication mechanism.

```java
@Bean
WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return web -> web.ignoring()
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
}
```

EDIT 1: It is also necessary to disable CSRF, added to snippets above.

EDIT 2: Adding an extra option to ignore H2 Console with Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Okay, I used your idea to make the whitelist String array into an AntPathRequestMatcher. It works, I can access the h2-console, when I test connection it's all fine, but when I try to connect it tells me that localhost refused to connect. Is it still an issue from the WebSecurityConfig class, or should I look elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. The new issue might be related to CSRF. You might need to add more security configs to get H2 Console to fully work. I'd start with `http.csrf().disable();`. Another option is to just ignore h2-console since it has its own authentication provider. I'll edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I'll add the code that works in the question, for other people.

Comment: I would recommend not to disable CSRF globally with `http.csrf().disable();`, but rather just for the h2 console: `http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")));`