# Spring Security 6 SecurityFilterChain precedence WebSecurityCustomizer

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-security

In spring security 6 I have configured the `securityFilterChain` as below:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/articles/feed").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users",  "/users/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/articles/**", "/profiles/**", "/tags").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
  }
```

To enable `h2-console` I have add this:

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/h2-console/**");
}
```

However I find that the configurations in `SecurityFilterChain` are precedence the configurations which I set in `WebSecurityCustomizer`. For example the `jwtRequestFilter` is still lunched for `/h2-console/**` urls

I can configure `/h2-console/*` in filter chain, But I want to know if there are other ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access the H2-console while using Spring Security (Spring Boot 3.0.2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75367159/how-can-i-access-the-h2-console-while-using-spring-security-spring-boot-3-0-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is at `webSecurityCustomizer`

The `requestMatchers` should be set to `AntPathRequestMatcher` not the default `MvcRequestMatcher`

```
@Bean
WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                       new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")
                    );
}
```